# driver.findElement(key) throws error in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the following code I want to take the key from the POM class, but it is throwing error for `driver.findElement(key)`.
The error showing is

> "The method findElement(By) in the type WebDriver is not applicable
>   for the arguments (String)"

```
WebDriver driver;

public void type(String key, String value) throws IOException {
    WebElement locator = driver.findElement(key);
    try {
        if (locator.isEnabled()) {
            locator.clear();
            locator.sendKeys(value);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        takeScreenShot("Error_"+ key+".jpeg");
        System.out.println("Typing failed on the key " + key);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method findElement(By) in the type WebDriver is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `findElement` receives [By](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) locator as parameter, not `String`

```
public void type(By by, String key, String value) {
     WebElement locator = driver.findElement(by);
}
```

Uses

```
type(By.id("id"), "key", "value");
```